# how does boost-asio know what port the server is running on?

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

So I was looking through the asio tutorials and I compiled the synchronious daytime client and the synchronious daytime server. I was playing around with the code on the server end by changing the port (in the site's code they hard coded 13 as the port) to be passed in through the command line.

I noticed that the client could only connect if the server was running on port 13 but interestingly enough nothing on the client said what port the server was on.

Can anyone explain to me how this program knows what port the server is running on and why it only works for port 13? Here's the code for the server http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime2/src.html

```
//
// client.cpp
// ~~~~~~~~~~
//
// Copyright (c) 2003-2010 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: client <host>" << std::endl;
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query(argv[1], "daytime");
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpoint_iterator = resolver.resolve(query);
    tcp::resolver::iterator end;

    tcp::socket socket(io_service);
    boost::system::error_code error = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;
    while (error && endpoint_iterator != end)
    {
      socket.close();
      socket.connect(*endpoint_iterator++, error);
    }
    if (error)
      throw boost::system::system_error(error);

    for (;;)
    {
      boost::array<char, 128> buf;
      boost::system::error_code error;

      size_t len = socket.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buf), error);

      if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
        break; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
      else if (error)
        throw boost::system::system_error(error); // Some other error.

      std::cout.write(buf.data(), len);
    }
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> interestingly enough nothing on the
>   client said what port the server was
>   on

server port in client is hardcoded here:

```
tcp::resolver::query query(argv[1], "daytime");
```

the key is "daytime". it's [a standard protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daytime_Protocol) and has its standard port number 13

Comment: So if you were to replace "daytime" with "echo" or "http" it would look for the ports normally associated with an echo or http server?

Comment: asio will look up the service name in the services file. Could also use a port literal. i.e. "13" instead of "daytime".

Comment: @Ferruccio, I think that would be a good piece of information to put directly into the answer, if possible.